# Extract from json into html using flask

Tags: python, json, flask

I'm writing a basic website that so far can take input from a form and add the values to a json file. I can also display the json data in a "json page". For this i do (json.dump(myGetJsonStuffFunc), indent = 4, sort_keys=True) This works wonders for the API part of the site.

What I also want to do is retrieve that information and display it in a "regular" html page where a user can get a much better overview.

As of right now I have function called SetValuesToHtml which i hope would set the value of a key to the variable and this is called in my route before the render_template call. But I can't figure out how to access neither the variable nor the information stored in it.

This is my full views.py: http://pastebin.com/cneKMtZf

The problems (i hope?) are these:

```
@app.route('/collection', methods = ['GET'])
def collectionH():
    data = SetValuesToHtml()

return render_template(
    'collection.html',
    title='This is our collection'
    )
```

and  the function:

```
def SetValuesToHtml():
    checkData()


    with open(filename+".json", "r") as infile:
        data = json.load(infile)
        infile.close()
        pass

    for tech in data['techs']:
        return data.endposition
    pass
```

I'm at a loss and don't really know where to look for help and thus i reach out to you. I'll gladly take a straight answer but just as happily i will take directions on what to read up on.

Thank you

Comment: There are issues with your indentation. `with open...` is not part of the function body. Even if this indentation is correct in your actual code, you cannot have `return` in a `for` loop because `return` will terminate the function on the first iteration.

Comment: A couple of other things: There is no need to call `close()` on a file that was opened using `with`. Also, I don't understand the intended function of `pass` at several points in your code. But please edit your question to ensure that the indentation matches your own code.

Comment: I didn't notice that when i pasted the code it did not auto align it the way it was in my ide. I apologize!

As for the close, i was told to always close the file after opening to ensure consistency. Since I've not run into problems I've assumed it worked. 

Pass i was taught is to let the function know that it has left the block and should move on. Either retrurn back when iterating or move on.

Did not know return worked liked that.

Comment: `with` is used so that you don't have to worry about `close()` since it automatically closes the file once you exit the indented block that follows it. Currently `for tech in data['techs']:` is not part of `SetValuesToHtml()` since it is not indented to be part of the function block, meaning that `return data.endposition` is meaningless. You do not need `pass` to end a function, that is determined by indentation and `return`. I know this isn't related to your main question, but this is complicating being able to pin down the issue.

Comment: Thank you! I edited my question again to correctly correspond with my indentation.

Comment: The indentation is wrong. You need to indent your `with` block and `for` block as well. Maybe take a look on basic Python programming and [indentation](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_blocks.php) before continuing.

Comment: As I've stated before I'm not used to formatting for SO and I'm learning. I'm sorry it came out wrong. The indentation is correct in my sourcecode.

Answer (score 0):

```
def SetValuesToHtml():
    checkData()


    with open(filename+".json", "r") as infile:
        data = json.load(infile)
        infile.close()
        pass

    for tech in data['techs']:
        return data.endposition
        pass
```

I suspect the last few lines should be

```
    return data['techs']['endpos']
```

instead of

```
    for tech in data['techs']:
        return data.endposition
        pass
```

According to the rest of your code, data['techs'] is a dict, not an object, and the key used elsewhere is 'endpos', not 'endposition'.

Comment: I tried this but merely got a new error. Will read up on  this though. Thank you for your time.

Comment: No problem. I hope you figure it out.